# Responsive Colspan (HTML Table)

Tags: jquery, html-table

I've created a table that works responsively across various screen sizes, with columns appearing and collapsing as desired to suit the different devices on which it can be loaded.

One issue I'm having, however, regards the `colspan` element. There are instances in which I would like to have a column stretch across an entire row.

A quick search of Github has found the following piece of jQuery:

```
$(function() {

    jQuery.fn.exists = function(){return this.length>0;}

    // Dynamic Colspan
    if($('[colspan="auto"]').exists())
    {
        $.each($('[colspan="auto"]'), function( index, value ) {
            var table = $(this).closest('table');    // Get Table
            var siblings = $(this).closest('tr').find('th:visible, td:visible').not('[colspan="auto"]').length; // Count colspan siblings
            var numCols = table.find('tr').first().find('th:visible, td:visible').length; // Count visible columns
            $(this).attr('colspan', numCols.toString()-siblings); // Update colspan attribute
        });
    }

});
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/afbora/6c98337a3455d45b6ae4e620d5cfbcf2

Here is an example of my table structure:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="auto">Divider</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see, I have a row which makes use of `colspan="auto"` and works fantastically well with the jQuery source from above.

Where this breaks down, however, is in any instance where a `<td>` has been selected to be hidden in a responsive stylesheet. Instead of switching from `colspan="6"` to `colspan="5"` behind the scenes (DOM), we end up with one row where the colspan is too large.

I've looked into `window.onresize` but am yet to have any success.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for first row without a `th` or a `td[colspan]`, then finding hidden `td` and then hiding that particular index on all rows except row:

```
$('table tr:not(:has(th)):not(:has(td[colspan]))').first().find('td:hidden').each(function(index) {
    $('table th:eq('+$(this).index()+'), table tr:not(:has(td:hidden)) td:eq(2)').hide();
});
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u7pe5ue7/)